# Project References vs Binary References

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

In my VS2010 WebSite Project, when I look at the references in the project properties, I see 3 types

1. GAC
2. Binary
3. Project

But in my WinForm app's project references table I don't see column referring to reference "type." Instead, I see a "Copy Local" column header. Yet, when I set  references from w/in my WinForm app, I can select a Project or a binary reference.

Why doesn't the WinForm property reference table display a Type column as does my WebSite properties References grid?

Answer (score 1):

VS isn't good at displaying the reference type in the gui, you cannot trust what is shows. The approach I'm using to be 100% sure is:

1. Open the project file with notepad and check if the reference is a <Reference> or <ProjectReference>.
2. Check if there's a matching directory in c:\windows\assembly\GAC*\*
3. Copy local (named <Private> in the project file) doesn't have anything to do with the reference type, it's for forcing the referenced assembly/project to be copied even if it isn't used by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why, but you can find out if you open up the object browser.  That will tell you what type of reference it is (file, project, GAC).